# Get the day(s) with the highest temperature from a table

Tags: matrix, lookup-tables, apl, dyalog

I'm trying to get the highest temperature day(s) in APL.

This is my code:

```
      days ← 'Monday' 'Tuesday' 'Wednesday' 'Thursday' 'Friday' 'Saturday' 'Sunday'
      temp ← 7 1 1 ⍴78 80 89 82 79 89 73
      Centigrade ← (5÷9) × {(⍵ - 32)} 
      AverageTemp ← days,⍪(+/÷≢)⍤1⊢Centigrade temp
      AverageTemp
┌─────────┬───────────┐
│Monday   │25.55555556│
├─────────┼───────────┤
│Tuesday  │26.66666667│
├─────────┼───────────┤
│Wednesday│31.66666667│
├─────────┼───────────┤
│Thursday │27.77777778│
├─────────┼───────────┤
│Friday   │26.11111111│
├─────────┼───────────┤
│Saturday │31.66666667│
├─────────┼───────────┤
│Sunday   │22.77777778│
└─────────┴───────────┘
```

Based on this sample, it should return Wednesday and Saturday

[link for quick test](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=days%20%E2%86%90%20%27Monday%27%20%27Tuesday%27%20%27Wednesday%27%20%27Thursday%27%20%27Friday%27%20%27Saturday%27%20%27Sunday%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20temp%20%E2%86%90%207%201%201%20%E2%8D%B478%2080%2089%2082%2079%2089%2073%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Centigrade%20%E2%86%90%20(5%C3%B79)%20%C3%97%20%7B(%E2%8D%B5%20-%2032)%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20AverageTemp%20%E2%86%90%20days%2C%E2%8D%AA(%2B%2F%C3%B7%E2%89%A2)%E2%8D%A41%E2%8A%A2Centigrade%20temp%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20AverageTemp&run)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's find what the maximum average temperature is:

```
      ⌈/AverageTemp[;2]
31.66666667
```

Now we want to find which rows have that value, as a mask:

```
      AverageTemp[;2] = ⌈/AverageTemp[;2]
0 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

We can then use that mask to filter the day names:

```
      days /⍨ AverageTemp[;2] = ⌈/AverageTemp[;2]
┌─────────┬────────┐
│Wednesday│Saturday│
└─────────┴────────┘
```

---

You code could be improved a bit, but that is off-topic here. If you want such feedback, please re-post [on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).